# String Joiner help needed in Java

Tags: java

I need a help in String Joiners and i want to append To_date to before string and the format after string..

```
public static StringJoiner inputDatesToQuery(
        List<FileSubmtRetrlStatus> fileSubmtRetrlStatus) {
    StringJoiner joinNames = new StringJoiner(",", "TO_DATE('", "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')");   // passing comma(,) and square-brackets as delimiter   
    for (FileSubmtRetrlStatus status : fileSubmtRetrlStatus) {
        joinNames.add(status.getFileSubRetDateTime());
        }
    return joinNames;
```

But the out put is coming like as below..

```
TO_DATE('2017-04-13 11:18:16,2017-04-13 11:17:44,2017-04-13 10:16:07',
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

But it should be like below...

```
TO_DATE('2017-04-13 11:18:16,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_DATE('2017-04-13 11:17:44,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_DATE('2017-04-13 10:16:07,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. In your case: what is the **input** data you intend to join?

Comment: This is how StringJoiner works. The prefix is for the whole StringJoiner instance, not for each item held within it.

Comment: Honestly `StringJoiner` should ~never be used directly; you should always be using `Stream.collect(joining(...))`

Answer (score 2):

StringJoiner only produces **one** output string. The example code in its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) is:

> The String "[George:Sally:Fred]" may be constructed as follows:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(":", "[", "]");
sj.add("George").add("Sally").add("Fred");
String desiredString = sj.toString();
```

I.e. it takes all the items you `add()`, separates them by the delimiter (in your case, a comma), and when you call `toString()` puts the prefix at the beginning of the full string, and the suffix at the end.

If you want to use StringJoiner, you need a separate one for each entry you want to output. You might want to look at Formatter or StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that output, you just need to setup the `StringJoiner` correctly:

```
String[] input = { "2017-04-13 11:18:16", "2017-04-13 11:17:44", "2017-04-13 10:16:07" };

StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),\nTO_DATE('",
                                       "TO_DATE('",
                                       ",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')");
for (String s : input)
    joiner.add(s);
System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```

*Output*

```
TO_DATE('2017-04-13 11:18:16,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_DATE('2017-04-13 11:17:44,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_DATE('2017-04-13 10:16:07,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Or to use Streams, like [@LouisWasserman thinks you should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417573/string-joiner-help-needed-in-java#comment73894345_43417573):

```
String[] input = { "2017-04-13 11:18:16", "2017-04-13 11:17:44", "2017-04-13 10:16:07" };

String joined = Arrays.stream(input)
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),\nTO_DATE('",
                                                  "TO_DATE('",
                                                  ",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')"));

System.out.println(joined);
```

Remember, the `prefix` only goes *before the first item*, the `suffix` only goes *after the last item*, and the `delimiter` should be the entire text you want *between items*.

↓ `prefix`
**TO_DATE('**​2017-04-13 11:18:16​**,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),** ← `delimiter`
**TO_DATE('**​2017-04-13 11:17:44,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_DATE('2017-04-13 10:16:07​**,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')** ← `suffix`

---

**UPDATE**

For the people who don't like repetition or string with newlines, do this:

```
String prefix = "TO_DATE('";
String suffix = ",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(suffix + ", " + prefix, prefix, suffix);
```

Comment: I would disagree with using StringJoiner in this way. It does print the desired result, but the code is not in line with the structure of the output. Logically, each line should be wholly part of one logical group. This solution is a bit hacky, and strays from OOP principles.

Comment: @4o2 What do you mean by *"not in line with the structure of the output"*? There is no "structure of output" in the question, other than a single string, and this code produces exactly the string the question is asking for. If you disagree with using `StringJoiner` at all, leave a comment in question or add your own answer talking about the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454), but it sure doesn't belong as a comment to my answer, especially since you didn't seem to leave the same comment to the other `StringJoiner` answer.

Comment: I mean that you're printing **lines**, right? Each line you print is in effect a separate piece of data. Making it so that a piece of logic deals with only parts of multiple lines (but not the same parts of each) brings up problems, e.g. what if I want to change the date formatting? I have to change the delimiter, **and** the suffix, even though both print the same information in the form of date format. What if this needed to be extended to print dates in several different formats? Etc.

Comment: @4o2 Ehh, no, I'm not printing lines. I'm printing a string (exactly **1** string) to show that it contains the text that the question was asking for. I have no idea what "pieces of logic" you think this question is about. To me, it looks like a comma-separated list of date literals, likely to be used in an `IN` clause in an Oracle SQL statement. Sure, it's not a good way to do it, since code should be using a `PreparedStatement` instead, but that's a separate issue. I was answering the question, not addressing the potential XY Problem.

Comment: @4o2 If user want to change the date format, the parameters to `StringJoiner` would not be the only code that would need to be changed, because the input text strings would have to be formatted differently too. Having the format listed twice is not an issue, and if you don't like the repetition, put it in a separate variable and insert it in both parameters to `StringJoiner`.